# Tabulator - Context Menu not showing after update the height of the table using setHeight()

Tags: jquery, tabulator

Context menu works well until I update the height of the table. Once I update the height, context menu shows only for the first row of the table and remaining rows are only showing browser's default context menu.

Is there any work around?

NOTE: I'm using v.5.5.2